# Uniform convergence check : $f_n\rightrightarrows f$ and $g_n\rightrightarrows g$ then ??

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Question is to check uniform convergence:

If $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ and $g_n \rightrightarrows g$ on $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ then

- $f_n+g_n \rightrightarrows  fg$ on $A\subset \mathbb{R}$
- $f_ng_n \rightrightarrows  fg$ on $A\subset \mathbb{R}$

I could see that :

$$|(f_n+g_n)(x)-(f+g)(x)|$$
$$=|(f_n(x)-f(x))+(g_n(x)-g(x))|$$
$$\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|g_n(x)-g(x)|$$

So, once I fix $\epsilon >o$ I have $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ and $N_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that :

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\text{ for all $n\geq N_1$ and for all $x\in A$}$$
and
$$|g_n(x)-g(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\text{ for all $n\geq N_2$ and for all $x\in A$}$$

So, $$|(f_n+g_n)(x)-(f+g)(x)|\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|g_n(x)-g(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} =\epsilon$$

for all $n\geq N=Max \{N_1,N_2\}$ and for all $x\in A$

Thus, I conclude that $f_n+g_n\rightrightarrows f+g$ on $A\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Now, I want to imitate same kind of logic here :

$$|(f_ng_n)(x)-(fg)(x)|$$
$$=|f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)-f_n(x)g(x)+f_n(x)g(x)|$$
$$=|f_n(x)[g_n(x)-g(x)]+g(x)[f_n(x)-f(x)]|$$

$$\leq |f_n(x)||[g_n(x)-g(x)]|+|g(x)||[f_n(x)-f(x)]|$$

$$\leq |f_n(x)|\frac{\epsilon}{2}+|g(x)|\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$=(|f(x)|+|g(x)|).\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

With this I believe that if i can make sure $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are bounded then I would have no problem and we would have :

$$f_ng_n \rightrightarrows  fg\text{ on } A\subset \mathbb{R}$$

Now, I will have problem if $f(x)$ and/or $g(x)$ is unbounded.

I believe for sure that in this case we do not have uniform convergence.

I have two requests :

- Please make sure if my idea is correct
- Please suggest some "natural" convergence in which limit function is not bounded.

EDIT : Just after asking for "natural" choice I got some idea :

If I take $f_n(x)=x+\frac{1}{n}$ then I would have limit function $f(x)=x$.

If i consider this convergence on whole $\mathbb{R}$ then :

> I have uniform convergence but limit function is not bounded.... :D :D :D

Now, I do not want to make it so complicated so, I want to take my $g_n(x)=f_n(x)$

I have $f_n(x)g_n(x)=(x+\frac{1}{n})^2$ we would have limit function as $f(x)g(x)=x^2$

But the convergence is not uniform when i see this convergence on whole of $\mathbb{R}$

SO, I would like to conclude that :

> $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ and $g_n \rightrightarrows g$ does not necessarily imply $f_ng_n \rightrightarrows  fg$

Comment: You're correct. You need bounded functions to show that the product function sequence converges uniformly.

Comment: Indeed, without the boundedness hypothesis, the product function may not converge uniformly. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350276/f-n-uniformly-converge-to-f-and-g-n-uniformly-converge-to-g-then-f-n-c) thread.

Comment: @Prism Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @ZackLi : Yes yes.. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Tojamaru : I thank you for your confidence on me... I would hope to get atleast JRF... :D